# Difference in the behavior of gcc 4.8.2 and gcc 4.9.0 in case of array size

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

On Gcc 4.8.2 version and before , below code fails to compile because array size is not compile time constant .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int f(){return 10;}
int main()
{
    int i=10;  
    int arr[f()]={}; //error 
}
```

When I tried to run similar code on 4.9 and onward ,same code got successfully compiled .

**Is it the compiler which allowed such code or it is the part of standard now ?**

Note : Above code fails to compile till **clang 3.7.1**

Comment: Is this C, or is it C++? VLAs are only standard in one of those. GCC supports them regardless.

Comment: It's a variable length array, vla, and it matters what the language is, please pick one

Answer (score 5):

Variable-length arrays are a C99 feature but allowed as an extension in GCC for C++. In C99, it's illegal to initialize a variable-length array:

> 6.7.8/3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type that is not a variable length array
>   type.

Whether or not it's illegal to initialize a VLA in GCC is not stated in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length), so you can assume it is **undefined behavior**. However, you also have another source of undefined behavior: `f()` has no return statement, therefore anything in your program can happen (a segmentation fault and exception were two different results I got in GCC 4.9.0)

The reason it compiles successfully in GCC 4.9.0 is only something the developers can answer. File a bug report.

**Speculation**: "Runtime-sized arrays" were [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html) to be added to C++14 but did not make the cut. GCC implements the original proposal in 4.9. The exception I mentioned earlier was a feature in the proposal:

> Add a new section just before 18.6.2.2 new.badlength:
>
> **Class `bad_array_length`**
>
> ```
>   namespace std {
>      class bad_array_length : public bad_alloc {
>      public:
>         bad_array_length() noexcept;
>      };
>   }
> ```
>
> The class `bad_array_length` defines the type of objects thrown as
>   exceptions by the implementation to report an attempt to allocate an
>   array of runtime bound with a size less than or equal to zero or
>   greater than an implementation-defined limit (8.3.4 dcl.array).
>
> ```
> bad_array_length() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: constructs an object of class `bad_array_length`.
>   *Remarks*: the result of calling `what()` on the newly constructed object is implementation-defined.

The docs state that in GCC 5 and beyond, [just regular VLAs](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#cxx) are supported now. If that's the case, the code should be rejected.

Comment: My only concern was , how this code was compiled on 4.9 version , so return type of f() doesn't matter to me .Anyways , I have updated it .